# Kendo dropdownlist cascade third level not showing optionlabel

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have three kendo dropdownlist with cascade, the first and second one are correct, but the third one dosen't show the optionlabel on page loading.

[image: imageOfDropDownList]

as you can see, the "Ciudad" dropdowlist is not showing the optionLabel even if it has it, as shown in the console.

I don't know why is it happening, as it is the same as the example in kendo demos:

[Link to demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist.html)

here is the code in razor:

```
        <div class="baseControlsLine rowLineHeight lineMap">
            <div class="labelControlWith"> @Html.Label(@BackOffice.lblCountry + ":", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "baseLabel mapLabel" })</div>
            <div class="baseControlSmall">
                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(c => c.Customer.MapCountry)
                    .OptionLabel(BackOffice.txtSelectCountry)
                    .Events(e => e.Close("CustomerCreateEdit.CreateAddresMap").DataBound("CustomerCreateEdit.DataBound"))
                    .DataTextField("Text")
                    .DataValueField("Value").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "baseTextbox" })
                    .DataSource(source => {
                        source.Read(read => {
                            read.Action(Constants.GET_COUNTRIES_SELECT_LIST, Constants.CUSTOMER_CONTROLLER);
                        });
                    }))
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.MapCountry)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="baseControlsLine rowLineHeight lineMap">
            <div class="labelControlWith"> @Html.Label(@BackOffice.lblProvince + ":", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "baseLabel mapLabel" })</div>
            <div class="baseControlSmall">
                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(c => c.Customer.MapProvince)
                    .Events(e => e.Close("CustomerCreateEdit.CreateAddresMap"))
                    .OptionLabel(BackOffice.txtSelectProvince)
                    .DataTextField("Text")
                    .DataValueField("Value").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "baseTextbox" })
                    .CascadeFrom("Customer_MapCountry")
                    .DataSource(source => {
                        source.Read(read => {
                            read.Action(Constants.GET_PROVINCES_SELECT_LIST, Constants.CUSTOMER_CONTROLLER).Data("CustomerCreateEdit.GetCountryId");
                        }).ServerFiltering(true);
                    }))
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.MapProvince)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="baseControlsLine rowLineHeight lineMap">
            <div class="labelControlWith"> @Html.Label(@BackOffice.lblCity + ":", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "baseLabel mapLabel" })</div>
            <div class="baseControlSmall">
                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(c => c.Customer.MapCity)
                    .Events(e => e.Close("CustomerCreateEdit.CreateAddresMap"))
                    .OptionLabel(BackOffice.txtSelectCity)
                    .DataTextField("Text")
                    .DataValueField("Value").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "baseTextbox" })
                    .CascadeFrom("Customer_MapProvince")
                    .DataSource(source => {
                        source.Read(read => {
                            read.Action(Constants.GET_CITIES_SELECT_LIST, Constants.CUSTOMER_CONTROLLER).Data("CustomerCreateEdit.GetProvinceId");
                        }).ServerFiltering(true);
                    }))
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer.MapCity)
            </div>
        </div>
```

here the code of javascript:

```
    GetCountryId: function () {
    /// <signature>
    ///   <summary>Devuelve el id del country para la cascada.</summary>
    /// </signature>
    return {
        id: $("#Customer_MapCountry").val()
    };
},
GetProvinceId: function () {
    /// <signature>
    ///   <summary>Devuelve el id de la provincia para la cascada.</summary>
    /// </signature>
    return {
        id: $("#Customer_MapProvince").val()
    };
},
```

and here the controllers:

```
    public JsonResult GetCitiesSelectList(int? id) {
        if (!id.HasValue)
            return Json(new SelectListItem() { Text = BackOffice.txtSelectCity }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        List<CityLanguage> listCity = _applicationCity.GetAllWithLanguage(id.Value).ToList();
        return Json(new SelectList(listCity, "IdCity", "Name"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public JsonResult GetProvincesSelectList(int? id) {
        if (!id.HasValue)
            return Json(new SelectListItem() { Text = BackOffice.txtSelectProvince }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        List<ProvinceLanguage> listProvince = _applicationProvince.GetAllWithLanguage(id.Value).ToList();
        return Json(new SelectList(listProvince, "IdProvince", "Name"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public JsonResult GetCountriesSelectList() {
        List<CountryLanguage> listCountryLanguage = _applicationCountry.GetAllWithLanguage().ToList();
        return Json(new SelectList(listCountryLanguage, "IdCountry", "Name"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**Edit:**

I had problems with the version of jquery, and I had to put the javascripts in this order:

jquery.
kendo.
jquery-ui.

it's posible that the error is for the order of the javascripts?

Also i have a version of jquery that it is not the one that comes with kendo.

It's posible that some of this things causes the weird behaviour of the third dropdownlist?

Comment: show drop down list code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try with `Placeholder` insted of `OptionLabel`.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(c => c.Customer.MapCountry)
                    .Placeholder(BackOffice.txtSelectCountry)
                    .Events(e => e.Close("CustomerCreateEdit.CreateAddresMap").DataBound("CustomerCreateEdit.DataBound"))
                    .DataTextField("Text")
                    .DataValueField("Value").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "baseTextbox" })
                    .DataSource(source => {
                        source.Read(read => {
                            read.Action(Constants.GET_COUNTRIES_SELECT_LIST, Constants.CUSTOMER_CONTROLLER);
                        });
                    }))
```

Comment: Hi Jaimin, sorry but I don't have the Placeholder option in my version of kendo, and I think that I have the last one.

Comment: @AlbertCortada ok then i have to check.